# Eclipse CDT indexer complains about C build-ins as unresolved symbols

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt, gnu

I have a GCC C based project in Eclipse CDT (Oxygen). In the Problems window, when I go I open C file in the main editor window, it lists bunch of unresolved symbols errors, many for the C and C library built-ins, like __func__.
If I understand it right this is Eclipse' indexer error, as the code compiles & builds fine. 
So this is just more of annoyance issue with my Eclipse setup I want to remove. I cannot figure out what is the issue with it however.  I've re-indexed N times, double checked includes, compiler / toolchain paths, still doesn't work.
The error(s) would be like:
Symbol '"__func__' could not be resolved
...
Symbol '__asm__ could not be resolved

__func__ is C standard, __asm__ is GCC/GNU keyword..

I tried something from here : https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/636348/

no luck.

Anyone knows how to fix the indexer here? Sometimes it also fails to resolve include paths of standard C headers, even though again, the code builds just fine.

Comment: Do you use a specific version of C++? (C++11 or C++1y)

Comment: @dceccon this is C only project (with some asm )

Comment: Error can be 
You can try one of this actions:
* Refresh your source code by Project Explorer window;

* Close and re-open your project (this action force the index reset);
* Try to change tool chain to another version.

Comment: Are you using newest version of eclipse? Some older version used to have problems with indexing which have been fixed in later versions.

Comment: @Aconcagua , no I have to use latest Oxygen update, not latest Eclipse / CDT release. So this is a  release older.

Comment: Hm, I *think* the issues were older (Luna or even Kepler). Never experienced exactly the same issue, though.

Comment: For now I just disabled all syntax error marking and indexer coloring in the edtior ... this is not optimal, but at least I don't get the error markers all over the place, and the symbol navigation seems to still work in the editor.

Comment: Can you give an example use of `__func__` which produces errors?

Comment: Sure, pretty much any encounter of it, all over.  E.g: printf("%s: %d, time %lu\n", __func__, err, get_timer(start));.   If I understand right this is Eclipse's indexer/syntaxer work. It/they also get 'confused' from (by highlighting) macros, underlining many as red.  Even though, Ctntrl-click on them works - that is seems indexer found where they belong to and I can navigate around, yet they highlighted.  Many issues, so I just turned it all off.

Comment: In addition, whats puzzling, I saw it complains about at least one standard include, like <stdbool.h>. Again, clicking on it, I could navigate to the correct include file (correct path inside the toolchain).   Again, noticing that, all code builds & works and no any compilation or other errors. So this indexing/syntaxing setup is not working for me. Particularly on large projects.   So far best solution for me, turn off all the  stuff under "Code Analysis" - that's what does all the coloring too, leaving Indexer working

Comment: To be more clear: I turn off all under Code Analysis but leave Indexer on  - so I have some/most navigation working at least.

Comment: sorry, that bold __func__ was supposed to be \___func___\    (the underlines make it bold .. )   ( how do you escape.. )

Comment: It's likely a configuration problem. I created a simple Hello World C project with `#include <stdio> int main() { printf("%s", __func__); }` and `__func__` was resolved fine. (Tried with Oxygen as well, same result.)

Comment: @HighCommander4 may be for very small projects.  You don't have say Linux sources lying around ? :P  But I will re-try with small too. Note: i'm using a cross-compiler toolchain, it could possibly be related ... (like it's not resolving paths right, or ..)